# How to find contours of soccer player in dynamic background

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, video-processing, object-detection, matlab-cvst

My project is a designation for a system which analyze soccer videos.  In a part of this project I need to detect  contours of players and everybody in the play field. For all players which don’t have occlusion with the advertisement billboards, I have used the color of play field (green) to detect contours and extract players. But I have problem with the situation that players or referee have occlusion with the advertisement billboards. Suppose a situation that advertisements on the billboards are dynamic (LED billboards). As you know in this situation finding the contours is more difficult because there is no static background color or texture. You can see two example of this condition in the following images.

[image: Referee occlusion]

[image]

NOTE: in order to find the position of occlusion, I use the region between the field line and advertisement billboards, because this region has the color of the field (green). This region is shown by a red rectangular in the following image.

[image]

I expect the result be similar to the following image.

[image]

Could anyone suggest an algorithm  to detect these contours?

Comment: It is unlikely youll get a straigthforward answer for this. What I would do: Get the motion from the videos. Most likely youll have some general motion going uniformly to some direction adn small blobs of motion doing something else. This small blobs will mostly be the players. Optical flow maybe?

Comment: You might also want to estimate the ground plane and leverage the fact that players are on it.

Comment: Nice animated GIFs btw, but unfortunately your question is too broad.  There are too many unconstrained variables in order to achieve good accuracy.  However, Dima's suggestions are a great place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try several things.

- Use `vision.PeopleDetector` object to detect people on the field. You can also track the detected people using `vision.KalmanFilter`, as in the [Tracking Pedestrians from a Moving Car](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/tracking-pedestrians-from-a-moving-car.html) example.
- Use [vision.OpticalFlow](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.opticalflow-class.html) object in the Computer Vision System Toolbox to compute optical flow. You can then analyze the resulting flow field to separate camera motion from the player motion.
- Use frame differencing to detect moving objects. The good news is that that will give you the contours of the people. The bad news is that it will give you many spurious contours as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I will try to use your suggestion.

Comment: I apply OpticalFlow method,but this method is used for distinguish camera motion from player motion,whereas I want to distinguish billboard advertisement motion from player motion. Consider that the camera can be fix (whit no movement), while advertisements and players can move.
Two other methods you mentioned, are similar this one.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, you need to detect all the players, no?  If you can assume that the camera is stationary, things become easier. You can use `vision.ForegroundDetector` to detect moving players and changing advertisements.  Then you can analyze the shape of the foreground regions (e. g. using `regionprops`) to separate  people from advertisements. Or you can use `vision.PeopleDetector`.

Answer (score 3):

Optical Flow would work for such problems as it captures motion information. Foreground extraction techniques using HMM or GMM or non-parametric may solve the problem as I have used for motion analysis in surveillance videos to detect anomaly (Background was static). Magnitude and orientation of optical flow seems to be an effective method. I have read papers on segmentation using optical flow. I hope this may help you.